# Как разбить CLOB колонку на несколько колонок?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, clob

Есть таблица с колонкой `data` типа CLOB. Значения имеют от 12000 до 15000 символов в этой колонке.

Допустим, если `data` содержит 12200 символов, то необходимо вывести несколько колонок:

```
data1        data2        data3        data4
-----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
first 4000   second 4000  third 4000   last 200
```

Как это можно сделать?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Splitting or Substr one column into multiple columns in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62284082) от участника [@joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12516505/joe)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62284082

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться фукцией [DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_LOB.html#GUID-F0F5D13A-C86C-4BC2-8394-8CBA3344D5CE).

Создайте процедуру, которая динамически поделит колонку на заданные кол-во колонок и длину:

```
create or replace procedure splitClob (
    tab varchar2, col varchar2, len int, pieces int, rc out sys_refcursor) as
    cols varchar2 (32000);
begin
    for i in 1..pieces loop
        cols := cols||'dbms_lob.substr ('||col||','||len||','||(len*(i-1)+1)||') '||col||i||',';
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line ('cols='||cols);
    open rc for 'select '||rtrim (cols, ',')||' from '||tab;
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
create table clobs (data) as
    select to_clob ('123abc456defzz') from dual union all
    select to_clob ('aaa111bbb222zz') from dual
/
var rc refcursor 
exec splitClob ('clobs','data', 4, 4, :rc) 

DATA1 DATA2 DATA3 DATA4
----- ----- ----- -----
123a  bc45  6def  zz   
aaa1  11bb  b222  zz
```

Comment: Обычные length и substr умеют работать с clob

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov Да, умеют.

Comment: Это была констатация факта, не вопрос. И имелось в виду, что не надо для этого dbms_lob юзать

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov Работать с substr будет, но небольшое отличие есть,   dbms_lob.substr взвращает varchar2, а substr (clob) вернёт clob. В вопросе, думаю, все таки нужен varchar2, иначе зачем колонку вообще разбивать. Как думаете?